# how to deal async when doing multiple http requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with my `http` requests in jQuery, I'm doing a requests that I'm passing to other `http` requests however it seems like not all requests are getting success, sometimes the value(s) I'm expecting to be returned is `undefined`.

Call this `config.js`

Initial request -

```
$.get('./config.json')
  .then(function(data) {
    let baseUrl = data.BaseApiUrl;
    2ndReq(baseUrl);
    3rdReq(baseUrl);
});
```

Other requests -

```
function 2ndReq(baseUrl) {
  $.get(baseUrl)
   .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    window.__env.passThis = data; // want it to be accessible in window property. Using this in my angular2 service for http request
 })
}
function 3rdReq(baseUrl) {
 $.get(baseUrl)
   .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    window.__env.passThisAswell = data;
 })
}
```

So, sometimes `2ndReq and 3rdReq` return values are `null/undefined`. So question is how can I deal with async/promises calls if you're doing multiple `http` requests at the same time, and pass it in `window` property?

Comment: your question and furthermore your intentions are really hard to understand. Please modify your question and at first try to explain why do you use jQuery with angular2

Comment: @smnbbrv nvm about the angular, I've removed that part in my question. So its just now these multiple http requests in jQuery.

Comment: read about promises

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with what you're doing now, so long as you do not need to use data from `2ndReq` inside of `3rdReq`. Where are you trying to access `window.__env.*`? Are you sure your web services are working correctly?

Comment: Yeah web services are working correctly, say I use it inside angular2 component/service and other external app within the porject.